# Priority Queue Array (c)

Tags: c, struct, priority-queue

I am building a priority queue, but rather than filling the PQ array with integers I am assigning a pointer to a struct. Heres the code for the two structures, intializer and insertion function for PQ:

```
typedef struct HeapStruct *PriorityQueue;
typedef struct Customer *CustomerP;

struct HeapStruct {
    int Capacity;
    int Size;
    int *Elements;
};

struct Customer {
    float arrivalT;
    float waitT;
    float departureT;
    float currentT;
    CustomerP *siblingR; //Used for linked list
};

PriorityQueue Initialize() {
    PriorityQueue H = (PriorityQueue) malloc(sizeof (struct HeapStruct));
    CustomerP sentinal = malloc(sizeof (struct Customer));
    sentinal->currentT = MinData;
    H->Capacity = 101;
    H->Size = 0;
    H->Elements[0] = &sentinal; //Syntax Error
    return H;
}

void Insert(CustomerP X, PriorityQueue H) {
    int i;
    if (IsFull(H)) {
        printf("Priority queue is full");
        return;
    }
    //Syntax errors
    for (i = ++H->Size; H->Elements[i/2]->currentT > X->currentT; i /= 2)
    H->Elements[i] = H->Elements[i/2];
    H->Elements[i] = X;
}
```

So I am trying to place a pointer in the Int array and doing comparisons such as H->Elements[i]->currentT, but I don't know how to handle a pointer to a struct in an array and access the struct from there.

Could anyone help me out with the syntax of this? I'll gladly provide more info if needed.

Comment: Is your intent that Elements reference a linear array of your values or pointers to individually allocated values? The distinction is important. What is here indicates the queue can hold a fixed number of items, and once capacity is reached, no more can be added. Is this the intent?

Comment: Its a prioriy queue, somewhat like a linked list. I have a function to remove an element from the priority queue, but I just didn't include that function in the posting. My intent is to add and remove items from the array, and each index should be a pointer to a struct. But I still need to be able to access the internals of the struct through the array. Hope I was clear.

Comment: It is now. The ceiling limit in the code was why I asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Elements` field in your `HeapStruct` needs to be defined appropriately based on what you want to store in your heap.  Then, you need to allocate memory for it before you use it.

So the first question, what do want in the heap?  You say you want customers (not `int`s, which is what you have), but do you want the structs themselves (`Customer`) or pointers to the structs (`Customer *` or `CustomerP`).  Assuming the latter you want:

```
struct HeapStruct {
    int Capacity;
    int Size;
    CustomerP *Elements;
};
```

Then you need to allocate space for it properly:

```
H = (PriorityQueue) malloc(sizeof (struct HeapStruct));
CustomerP sentinal = malloc(sizeof (struct Customer));
sentinal->currentT = MinData;
H->Capacity = 101;
H->Size = 0;
H->Elements = malloc(sizeof(CustomerP) * H->Capacity);
H->Elements[0] = sentinal;
```

Comment: +1 Also correct (and since when does the former Senator from Conn post solutions on SO? =P )

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping clear help up my confusion on this.

Answer (score 2):

you want Eements to be

```
CustomerP*
```

then you need to assign some memory to  `H->Elements`  so that i can hold all the pointers.

maybe :-

```
H->Elements =  malloc(sizeof (CustomerP) * H->Capacity);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it works without giving me syntax errors, but the array doesnt build properly. Tried debugging it using gdb in Netbeans and the array is just a list with one struct and empty siblingR to anohter empty struct (infinit). So the only struct that get inserted is the sentinal struct (position [0]). So then I tried using an int array to correct the problem, but thats not working out.

Comment: This is the correct answer, Dice. The array of pointers should be allocated as Keith describes. The indexing, allocation of new nodes and setting their references in that array, and placement of your sentinel node are another issue, but if you want each node to be dynamically allocation, and the array of those nodes to be dynamically sizable, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
H->Elements = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
H->Elements[0] = &sentinal;
```

OR
    H->Elements = &sentinal;

Both should work.